# JS regexp. Исключение группы из запоминания

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Имеется файл с строками вида

`xxxxx@mail.ru      id`

Нужно вытащить `xxxxx@mail.ru` и `id`

Регулярное выражение для получения почты `^(.+)(?:\s+)` почему-то тянет за собой еще и пробелы, хотя указал их исключение. Что я делаю неправильно? Интерактивный пример здесь https://regex101.com/r/hhL2d5/2/

Comment: `^([^\s]+)` , хотя, ни ваш вариант, ни этот, я бы не назвал "_Регулярное выражение для получения почты_". В группировке без обратной связи  `(?:\s+)`, я тут вообще смысла не вижу

Comment: `^(.+?)(?:\s+)`

Comment: @Deonis спасибо, в общем нужна даже не почта, а первый блок текста до пробела.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться следующим регулярным выражением:

```
^(\S+)\s+(\S+)
```

[Онлайн-демо](https://regex101.com/r/hhL2d5/3)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(\S+)` - захватывающая подмаска №1: 1 и более символов, отличных от пробельных символов
- `\s+` - 1 и более пробельных символов
- `(\S+)` - захватывающая подмаска №2: 1 и более символов, отличных от пробельных символов.

Код на JavaScript:

```js
var s = "xxxxx@mail.ru      id";
var res = s.match(/^(\S+)\s+(\S+)/);
console.log(res[1], "и", res[2]);
```

Если нужно получить подстроку до первого пробела, можно использовать `/^\S+/`:

```js
console.log("xxxxx@mail.ru      id".match(/^\S+/)[0]);
```